# CMake - organize lib files into subfolders

Tags: c++, cmake

Is it possible to organise the files in a lib into subfolders?
For example:

```
 lib_a\
   |___ sub_1\
   |       |__ include\
   |       |       |______ file_1.h
   |       |______ file_1.cpp
   |___ sub_2\
   |       |__ include\
   |       |       |______ file_2.h
   |       |______ file_2.cpp
   |___ sub_3\
   |       |__ include\
   |       |       |______ file_3.h
   |       |______ file_3.cpp
   |___ CMakeLists.txt
```

I cannot manage to make it work. This is how I am doing it:

```
set(LIBA_SRC
     "./sub_1/file_1.cpp"
     "./sub_2/file_2.cpp"
     "./sub_3/file_3.cpp"
)
set(LIBA_H
     "./sub_1/include/file_1.h"
     "./sub_2/include/file_2.h"
     "./sub_3/include/file_3.h"
)

add_library(lib_a ${LIBA_SRC} ${LIBA_H})
target_compile_features(lib_a PUBLIC cxx_std_14)
set_target_properties(lib_a PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

target_include_directories(lib_a PUBLIC 
    "sub_1/include"
    "sub_2/include"
    "sub_3/include"
    )
```

Edit:
I thought the problem was related with how I implemented the cmake for lib_a but it looks like the problem is from where I link the library lib_a to.
I have an application that I have defined as:

```
add_executable(my_app "my_app.cpp" )
target_compile_features(my_app PRIVATE cxx_std_14)

target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE lib_a)
```

I can run the program but the editor says for each #include "file_1.h", #include "file_2.h", and #include "file_3.h"

> E0020 identifier "file_1" is undefined

and

> E1696 cannot open source file "file_1.h"

And same for file_2.h and file_3.h. However, as said before, the program can compile and run correctly.

Comment: What does "cannot manage to make it work" mean? Is CMake complaining about the unbalanced `"` characters in your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I forgot to close the string with ", I have just corrected the post/question.
The problem is that Visual Studio says that it cannot find the source codes in the editor. However, strangely I can compile it and run it.

Comment: Edit your question with the actual error message then.

Comment: I've just updated the question. I have also realised that the problem can be somewhere else. It's a bigger project and I am trying to reduce it to the minimum here to easily explain it. Thank you